# slicing pandas DataFrame with negative index with ix() method

Tags: indexing, dataframe, pandas, slice

DataFrame.ix() does not seem to slice the DataFrame that I want when negative indexing is used.

I have a DataFrame object and want to slice the last 2 rows.

```
    In [90]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))

    In [91]: df
    Out[91]: 
            0         1         2         3
    0  1.985922  0.664665 -2.800102  1.695480
    1  0.580509  0.782473  1.032970  1.559917
    2  0.584387  1.798743  0.095950  0.071999
    3  1.956221  0.075530 -0.391008  1.692585
    4 -0.644979 -1.959265  0.749394 -0.437995
    5 -1.204964  0.653912 -1.426602  2.409855
    6  1.178886  2.177259 -0.165106  1.145952
    7  1.410595 -0.761426 -1.280866  0.609122
    8  0.110534 -0.234781 -0.819976  0.252080
    9  1.798894  0.553394 -1.358335  1.278704
```

One way to do it:

```
    In [92]: df[-2:]
    Out[92]: 
              0         1         2         3
    8  0.110534 -0.234781 -0.819976  0.252080
    9  1.798894  0.553394 -1.358335  1.278704
```

Anther way to do it:

```
    In [93]: df.ix[len(df)-2:, :]
    Out[93]: 
              0         1         2         3
    8  0.110534 -0.234781 -0.819976  0.252080
    9  1.798894  0.553394 -1.358335  1.278704
```

Now I want to use negative indexing, but having problem:

```
    In [94]: df.ix[-2:, :]
    Out[94]: 
              0         1         2         3
    0  1.985922  0.664665 -2.800102  1.695480
    1  0.580509  0.782473  1.032970  1.559917
    2  0.584387  1.798743  0.095950  0.071999
    3  1.956221  0.075530 -0.391008  1.692585
    4 -0.644979 -1.959265  0.749394 -0.437995
    5 -1.204964  0.653912 -1.426602  2.409855
    6  1.178886  2.177259 -0.165106  1.145952
    7  1.410595 -0.761426 -1.280866  0.609122
    8  0.110534 -0.234781 -0.819976  0.252080
    9  1.798894  0.553394 -1.358335  1.278704
```

How do I use negative indexing with DataFrame.ix() correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          0         1         2         3
0 -3.100926 -0.580586 -1.216032  0.425951
1 -0.264271 -1.091915 -0.602675  0.099971
2 -0.846290  1.363663 -0.382874  0.065783
3 -0.099879 -0.679027 -0.708940  0.138728
4 -0.302597  0.753350 -0.112674 -1.253316
5 -0.213237 -0.467802  0.037350  0.369167
6  0.754915 -0.569134 -0.297824 -0.600527
7  0.644742  0.038862  0.216869  0.294149
8  0.101684  0.784329  0.218221  0.965897
9 -1.482837 -1.325625  1.008795 -0.150439

In [3]: df.ix[-2:]
Out[3]: 
          0         1         2         3
0 -3.100926 -0.580586 -1.216032  0.425951
1 -0.264271 -1.091915 -0.602675  0.099971
2 -0.846290  1.363663 -0.382874  0.065783
3 -0.099879 -0.679027 -0.708940  0.138728
4 -0.302597  0.753350 -0.112674 -1.253316
5 -0.213237 -0.467802  0.037350  0.369167
6  0.754915 -0.569134 -0.297824 -0.600527
7  0.644742  0.038862  0.216869  0.294149
8  0.101684  0.784329  0.218221  0.965897
9 -1.482837 -1.325625  1.008795 -0.150439
```

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2600

Note that `df[-2:]` will work:

```
In [4]: df[-2:]
Out[4]: 
          0         1         2         3
8  0.101684  0.784329  0.218221  0.965897
9 -1.482837 -1.325625  1.008795 -0.150439
```

Answer (score 3):

`ix`'s main purpose is to allow numpy like indexing with support for row and column labels.  So I'm not sure your use-case is the intended purpose.  Here are a couple of ways I can think of, mostly trivial:

```
In [142]: df.ix[:][-2:]
Out[142]:
          0         1         2         3
8  0.386882 -0.836112 -0.108250 -0.433797
9  0.642468 -0.399255 -0.911456 -0.497720

In [161]: df.ix[df.index[-2:],:]
Out[161]:
          0         1         2         3
8  0.386882 -0.836112 -0.108250 -0.433797
9  0.642468 -0.399255 -0.911456 -0.497720
```

I don't think `ix` supports negative indexing at all.  It seems to just ignore it altogether:

```
In [181]: df.ix[-100:,:]
Out[181]:
          0         1         2         3
0 -1.144137 -1.042034 -2.158838  0.674055
1 -0.424184  1.237318 -1.846130  0.575357
2 -0.844974 -0.541060  2.197364 -0.031898
3  0.846263  1.244450 -1.570566 -0.477919
4 -0.193445  0.171045 -0.235587 -1.185583
5  1.361539 -1.107389 -1.321081 -0.776407
6  0.505907 -1.364414 -2.093770  0.144016
7 -0.888465 -0.329153  0.491264 -0.363472
8  0.386882 -0.836112 -0.108250 -0.433797
9  0.642468 -0.399255 -0.911456 -0.497720
```

Edit: From the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-advanced) we have:

> Label-based indexing with integer axis labels is a thorny topic. It
>   has been discussed heavily on mailing lists and among various members
>   of the scientific Python community. In pandas, our general viewpoint
>   is that labels matter more than integer locations. Therefore, with an
>   integer axis index only label-based indexing is possible with the
>   standard tools like .ix. The following code will generate exceptions:
>
> ```
> s = Series(range(5))
> s[-1]
> df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4))
> df
> df.ix[-2:]
> ```
>
> This deliberate decision was made to prevent ambiguities and subtle
>   bugs (many users reported finding bugs when the API change was made to
>   stop “falling back” on position-based indexing).