# How to get the last N rows of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have pandas dataframe `df1`:

```
    STK_ID  RPT_Date  TClose   sales  discount
0   000568  20060331    3.69   5.975       NaN
1   000568  20060630    9.14  10.143       NaN
2   000568  20060930    9.49  13.854       NaN
3   000568  20061231   15.84  19.262       NaN
4   000568  20070331   17.00   6.803       NaN
5   000568  20070630   26.31  12.940       NaN
6   000568  20070930   39.12  19.977       NaN
7   000568  20071231   45.94  29.269       NaN
8   000568  20080331   38.75  12.668       NaN
9   000568  20080630   30.09  21.102       NaN
10  000568  20080930   26.00  30.769       NaN
```

I wanted to select the last 3 rows and tried `df1.ix[-3:]`, but it returns all the rows. Why? How to get the last 3 rows of `df1`? I'm using pandas 0.10.1.

Comment: You can use `df[-3:]` to produce the results you want. This was addressed as a bug by WesM.  Not sure if/when it's getting fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035817/slicing-pandas-dataframe-with-negative-index-with-ix-method

Comment: @Zelazny7 I don't think that's right. I think negative slicing with `ix` was a bug, but passing negative slices to `__getitem__` is not. `df.iloc[-3:]` internally delegates to `__getitem__` with the same arguments, do `df[-3:]` is a shortcut for `df.iloc[-3:]`, not a bug.

Comment: Remember ix is being deprecated.

Answer (score 556, accepted):

Don't forget `DataFrame.tail`! e.g. `df1.tail(10)`

Answer (score 112):

This is because of using integer indices (`ix` selects those by *label* over -3 rather than *position*, and this is by design: see [integer indexing in pandas "gotchas"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#integer-indexing)*).

*In newer versions of pandas prefer loc or iloc to remove the ambiguity of ix as position or label:

```
df.iloc[-3:]
```

*see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix)*.

As Wes points out, in this specific case you should just use tail!

Comment: @DavidWolever I can't reproduce your IndexError on 0.14.1, df.iloc[-5:] works fine for me with your example. Which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 14):

> ### How to get the last N rows of a pandas DataFrame?

If you are slicing by position, `__getitem__` (i.e., slicing with`[]`) works well, and is the most succinct solution I've found for this problem.

```
pd.__version__
# '0.24.2'

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaabbbbc'), 'B': np.arange(1, 9)})
df

   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  b  4
4  b  5
5  b  6
6  b  7
7  c  8
```

```
df[-3:]

   A  B
5  b  6
6  b  7
7  c  8
```

This is the same as calling `df.iloc[-3:]`, for instance (`iloc` internally delegates to `__getitem__`).

---

As an aside, if you want to find the last N rows for each group, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df.groupby('A').tail(2)

   A  B
1  a  2
2  a  3
5  b  6
6  b  7
7  c  8
```

Answer (score 0):

The top two answers suggest that there may be 2 ways to get the same output but if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f5bb77564e447fb023c3e02539e3178fd53e3cb9/pandas/core/generic.py#L5975), `.tail(n)` is a syntactic sugar for `.iloc[-n:]`. For the task of getting the last n rows as in the title, they are exactly the same.

However, they are different if we want to get the last n rows of a group because there is no groupby.iloc but there is `groupby.tail` (and `groupby.nth`).

---

Another, slightly obscure, way to get the last rows is via `take()` which is similar to `numpy.take`; however, we have to pass a list of indices: `df.take(range(-n, 0))`.

The main difference of this from `tail`/`iloc` is related to error handling. If the dataframe has less than n rows, but we try to get the last n rows, `tail`/`iloc` returns the entire dataframe while `take` raises an error. This comes in handy if you're making calls to an API or webscraping etc. where you expect the dataframe to have a certain shape but something fails unexpectedly; `tail` may silently produce a wrong output while `take` can alert you.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
df.tail(5)             # <--- entire dataframe
df.iloc[-5:]           # <--- entire dataframe
df.take(range(-5,0))   # <--- IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```