# How can we find the last row, in a specific column, in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame named 'data["df"]'.  The data looks like this.

[image]

How can I get the last row in the column named 'adjclose'?  The number that I want is '28.430000'.

I am trying to append this to a list.  I tested this piece of code:

```
print(str(data.iloc[-1, data.columns.get_loc("adjclose")]) = 0))
```

I get this: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iloc'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my full code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import random


# set seed, so we can get the same results after rerunning several times
np.random.seed(314)
tf.random.set_seed(314)
random.seed(314)



def load_data(ticker, n_steps=50, scale=True, shuffle=True, lookup_step=1, 
                test_size=0.2, feature_columns=['adjclose', 'volume', 'open', 'high', 'low']):
    # see if ticker is already a loaded stock from yahoo finance
    if isinstance(ticker, str):
        # load it from yahoo_fin library
        df = si.get_data(ticker)
    elif isinstance(ticker, pd.DataFrame):
        # already loaded, use it directly
        df = ticker
    # this will contain all the elements we want to return from this function
    result = {}
    # we will also return the original dataframe itself
    result['df'] = df.copy()
    # make sure that the passed feature_columns exist in the dataframe
    for col in feature_columns:
        assert col in df.columns, f"'{col}' does not exist in the dataframe."
    if scale:
        column_scaler = {}
        # scale the data (prices) from 0 to 1
        for column in feature_columns:
            scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
            df[column] = scaler.fit_transform(np.expand_dims(df[column].values, axis=1))
            column_scaler[column] = scaler

        # add the MinMaxScaler instances to the result returned
        result["column_scaler"] = column_scaler
    # add the target column (label) by shifting by `lookup_step`
    df['future'] = df['adjclose'].shift(-lookup_step)
    # last `lookup_step` columns contains NaN in future column
    # get them before droping NaNs
    last_sequence = np.array(df[feature_columns].tail(lookup_step))
    # drop NaNs
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    sequence_data = []
    sequences = deque(maxlen=n_steps)
    for entry, target in zip(df[feature_columns].values, df['future'].values):
        sequences.append(entry)
        if len(sequences) == n_steps:
            sequence_data.append([np.array(sequences), target])
    # get the last sequence by appending the last `n_step` sequence with `lookup_step` sequence
    # for instance, if n_steps=50 and lookup_step=10, last_sequence should be of 59 (that is 50+10-1) length
    # this last_sequence will be used to predict in future dates that are not available in the dataset
    last_sequence = list(sequences) + list(last_sequence)
    # shift the last sequence by -1
    last_sequence = np.array(pd.DataFrame(last_sequence).shift(-1).dropna())
    # add to result
    result['last_sequence'] = last_sequence
    # construct the X's and y's
    X, y = [], []
    for seq, target in sequence_data:
        X.append(seq)
        y.append(target)
    # convert to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    # reshape X to fit the neural network
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[2], X.shape[1]))
    # split the dataset
    result["X_train"], result["X_test"], result["y_train"], result["y_test"] = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    # return the result
    return result

def create_model(sequence_length, units=256, cell=LSTM, n_layers=2, dropout=0.3,
                loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="rmsprop", bidirectional=False):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(n_layers):
        if i == 0:
            # first layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
        elif i == n_layers - 1:
            # last layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=False)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=False))
        else:
            # hidden layers
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True))
        # add dropout after each layer
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=optimizer)
    return model


# Window size or the sequence length
N_STEPS = 100
# Lookup step, 1 is the next day
LOOKUP_STEP = 1
# test ratio size, 0.2 is 20%
TEST_SIZE = 0.2
# features to use
FEATURE_COLUMNS = ["adjclose", "volume", "open", "high", "low"]
# date now
date_now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
### model parameters
N_LAYERS = 3
# LSTM cell
CELL = LSTM
# 256 LSTM neurons
UNITS = 256
# 40% dropout
DROPOUT = 0.4
# whether to use bidirectional RNNs
BIDIRECTIONAL = False
### training parameters
# mean absolute error loss
# LOSS = "mae"
# huber loss
LOSS = "huber_loss"
OPTIMIZER = "adam"
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 2


# save the dataframe
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

start_date = date(2020, 3, 1)
end_date = date(2020, 9, 18)
days = np.busday_count(start_date, end_date)



# Apple stock market

tickers = ['CHIS']

thelen = len(tickers)

z=0
all_stocks=[]

for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_data_filename = os.path.join("data", f"{ticker}_{date_now}.csv")
    # model name to save, making it as unique as possible based on parameters
    model_name = f"{date_now}_{ticker}-{LOSS}-{OPTIMIZER}-{CELL.__name__}-seq-{N_STEPS}-step-{LOOKUP_STEP}-layers-{N_LAYERS}-units-{UNITS}"
    if BIDIRECTIONAL:
        model_name += "-b"
    
    
    # create these folders if they does not exist
    if not os.path.isdir("results"):
        os.mkdir("results")
    if not os.path.isdir("logs"):
        os.mkdir("logs")
    if not os.path.isdir("data"):
        os.mkdir("data")
        
    
    # load the data
    data = load_data(ticker, N_STEPS, lookup_step=LOOKUP_STEP, test_size=TEST_SIZE, feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS)
    
    # save the dataframe
    data["df"].to_csv(ticker_data_filename)
    
    # construct the model
    model = create_model(N_STEPS, loss=LOSS, units=UNITS, cell=CELL, n_layers=N_LAYERS,
                        dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER, bidirectional=BIDIRECTIONAL)
    
    # some tensorflow callbacks
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join("results", model_name + ".h5"), save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs", model_name))
    
    history = model.fit(data["X_train"], data["y_train"],
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=(data["X_test"], data["y_test"]),
                        callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard],
                        verbose=1)
    
    model.save(os.path.join("results", model_name) + ".h5")
    
    
    # after the model ends running...or during training, run this
    # tensorboard --logdir="logs"
    # http://localhost:6006/
    
    
    data = load_data(ticker, N_STEPS, lookup_step=LOOKUP_STEP, test_size=TEST_SIZE,
                    feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS, shuffle=False)
    
    # construct the model
    model = create_model(N_STEPS, loss=LOSS, units=UNITS, cell=CELL, n_layers=N_LAYERS,
                        dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER, bidirectional=BIDIRECTIONAL)
    
    model_path = os.path.join("results", model_name) + ".h5"
    model.load_weights(model_path)
    
    
    # evaluate the model
    mse, mae = model.evaluate(data["X_test"], data["y_test"], verbose=0)
    # calculate the mean absolute error (inverse scaling)
    mean_absolute_error = data["column_scaler"]["adjclose"].inverse_transform([[mae]])[0][0]
    #print("Mean Absolute Error:", mean_absolute_error)
    
    
    def predict(model, data, classification=False):
        # retrieve the last sequence from data
        last_sequence = data["last_sequence"][:N_STEPS]
        # retrieve the column scalers
        column_scaler = data["column_scaler"]
        # reshape the last sequence
        last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((last_sequence.shape[1], last_sequence.shape[0]))
        # expand dimension
        last_sequence = np.expand_dims(last_sequence, axis=0)
        # get the prediction (scaled from 0 to 1)
        prediction = model.predict(last_sequence)
        # get the price (by inverting the scaling)
        predicted_price = column_scaler["adjclose"].inverse_transform(prediction)[0][0]
        return predicted_price
    
    
    # predict the future price
    future_price = predict(model, data)
    print(f"Future price after {LOOKUP_STEP} days is ${future_price:.2f}")

    z=z+1
    print(str(z) + ' of ' + str(thelen))

    
    # print(new_seriesdata['Adj Close'].iloc[-1])
    all_stocks.append(ticker + ' act: ' + str(future_price) + ' prd: ' + str(future_price))
```

Comment: It appears that your `data` is not a dataframe, but a dictionary. Please provide a complete example. However, from your remark "I have a data frame named 'data["df"]'", perhaps `data` isn't your dataframe but `data['df']` is?

Comment: Once you do have your dataframe, note that there's a well documented function to get the last records, called `tail()`. Something as simple as `your_df.tail(1)['adjclose']` is probably all you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last N rows of a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663004/how-to-get-the-last-n-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: If it's a dictionary, you can get the item you need simply using `data['adjclose'][-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Grismar answered, yours is currently defined as a dictionary. If you get it in a DataFrame format, you could also represent it as a list of values from a column:

```py
a = your_df['adjclose']
```

And then retrieve the last value of the list (last row accordingly).

```py
print(a[len(a)-1])
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm kind of lost here.  I tried these options:

df['adjclose']
Yields: KeyError: 'adjclose'

df.tail(1)['adjclose']
Yields: KeyError: 'adjclose'

df['adjclose'][-1]
Yields: KeyError: 'adjclose'

Comment: Can you please post how you are structuring your df? Seems like adjclose is not present in your df.

Comment: I just posted my full code.  It may be a bit confusing, but hopeful it helps more than ti hurts!!

Comment: @ Grismar & pavel, you are both right.  THese are two different ways to do the same thing.  Thanks a lot!!  One more question.  Why do I get 450 records in 'data["df"]' but I only have 147 days in 'days'.  I would expect 147 records in 'data["df"]'.  Why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: @ Grismar & pavel, I figured it out.  I just sliced the data frame and I'm getting what I want now.  Thanks everyone!!